# How do I fix incorrect inline Javascript indentation in Vim?

Tags: javascript, vim

I can't seem to get inline Javascript indenting properly in Vim. Consider the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  // Closing brace correctly indented
    $("input").focus(function() {
      $(this).closest("li").addClass("cur-focus");
    }); // <-- I had to manually unindent this

  // Closing brace incorrectly indented
    $("input").blur(function() {
      $(this).closest("li").removeClass("cur-focus");
      }); // <-- This is what it does by default. Argh!

  });
```

Vim seems to insist on automatically indenting the closing brace shown in the second case there. It does the same if I re-indent the whole file. How do I get it to automatically indent using the more standard JS indenting style seen in the first case?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use [JavaScript Indent: Javascript indenter (HTML indent is included)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081) by Preston Koprivica. Thanks for the heads-up from [oligofren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620247/how-do-i-fix-incorrect-inline-javascript-indentation-in-vim/4183349#4183349) - give him an up-vote.

Comment: I was just suggesting in comment to your reply that maybe the vim syntax file might be missing. :)

Comment: i've been wondering why javascript indentation is all wonky, thanks a lot!

Comment: I jave indendation-issues with the provided OOP javascript indentation, in particular with jQuery-code. See the answer of oligofren for a working indentation plugin.

Comment: is it possible to set the indentation to 2 space?

Comment: @disappearedng: Yes. `set ts=2`, `set sw=2`, `set expandtab`

Comment: Jesus, this plugin blows the big one. Incorrectly indents everything. I'll comment again when I find a better one.

Comment: If you got the 1.0 release of this and this indenter isn't doing anything for you, you may need to set 'indentkeys' to something that you prefer, it is cleared in the script itself so by default it won't automatically indent as you type. The old beta 3 release did not seem to do this.

Comment: @aphax I tried setting `indentkeys` to the regular default `"0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e")` from `help indentkeys` and it didn't help. Switching back to `b3.0` did resolve the issue, however.

Answer (score 88):

The most comprehensive and bug-free Javascript indentation script is [the one by Preston Koprivica](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081). <strike>The so called OOP script that is in the proposed answer has severe bugs, and does not indent code properly that has square brackets.</strike>

Comment: This one is the only one really working for my js-files (consisting mainly of jQuery code - multiple braces and curly braces often on the same line)

Comment: Note, I updated the accepted answer some time ago to link to Preston Koprivica's script. Thanks to oligofren for the pointer.

Comment: Note: Something in my vim configuration causes the `1.0` version of Preston's script to not indent properly on new lines. Version `b3.0` works just fine, however. If you have troubles with `1.0`, try `b3.0` instead.

Comment: You are lucky then, version b3.0 does not indent properly for me :)

Answer (score 17):

The scripts mentioned above do not format the closure-syntax often used in jQuery correctly:

```
$(function() {
  // only one level of indentation, not two
});
```

This script works better for me: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2765

Comment: Thanks for this! As a side note, make sure get the version from github, which is much, much newer.

Comment: This works much better than the higher voted one for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, this indentation script fails on simple cases like putting the opening brace of a block on a newline, and doesn't respect the users tab expansion settings, for example indenting with 3 spaces when I have it configured to expand to 4.

Answer (score 11):

Most of these answers are from 2009 and, frankly, are out of date.

[vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) is much more recent and up-to-date than [Preston's script.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081)

Installation is a bit more complicated if you haven't started using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) yet, but it doesn't seem to suffer from the issues of the alternatives.

Comment: Note that `vim-javascript` does not support javascript embedded in html files (as far as I can tell).

Comment: This is the best javascript plugin that I've come across. Still good in 2017

Comment: This package messes up my javascript.  Preston's still works perfectly. Ironically its 2018 and wih ES6, prestons still does a better job.

Answer (score 7):

maybe some combination of these settings should be in your VIMRC file.

```
syntax on 
set syn=auto 
set showmatch 
filetype on 
filetype plugin on 
filetype indent on 
set tabstop=4 
set softtabstop=4 
set shiftwidth=4 
set expandtab
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions, but I've already got most of these set and they don't seem to help.

Comment: I notice with vim sometimes matching braces shift one tab stop until I skip past that line in the code.  I *thought* that "filetype plugin on & filetype indent on" were supposed to drive that.  do you have a syntax file for javascript?  (I'm not working with JS, so don't know if it's needed or not

Comment: Without some of these settings, the Koprivica script won't work.

Comment: For me every time I start a new line the indentation is too many than expected, turns out I was missing the `shiftwidth` setting. I guess it was set to `4` by default, but in my default setting, all indentation are in `2`. Having `set shiftwidth=2` solved me issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue.  This is the best of all Javascript indentation scripts:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1840

It requires the IndentAnything plugin

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1839

As an added bonus, I wrote this indent script that will make Javascript blocks quite pretty.  It uses the default html indenter by default (and the IndentAnything one when within a Javascript block)

http://gist.github.com/371902

Comment: looks like this does most things "wrong", like adding two levels of indent after (function() { . Also loses extreme points for not having a github/bibucket repo.

Comment: Agree while it's better than most upvoted answer still is not good.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes here please note the `vim-javascript` by `pangloss` at https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript helped me so far, i.e. Vim 7.4. And the above solutions from oligofren and Charles Roper didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install plugins specialised for Javascript, you can learn the built-in Vim options for indentation. Vim has quite a few options, and some of the indenting styles like `cindent`, `smartindent` and `indentexpr` have options of their own.

To check whether you are using `cindent` or `smartindent` or `indentexpr`, run:

```
:set cindent?
:set smartindent?
:set indentexpr?
```

Despite the name, `cindent` doesn't just apply to C programs, it can apply to a bunch of programming languages that share roughly the same syntax, including Javascript. Have a look at [`:help C-indenting`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#C-indenting) for documentation about this. You can adjust the settings particularly with a line like this one, see [`:help 'cinoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'cinoptions') and [`:help cinoptions-values`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values). Here's an example configuration:

```
:au FileType js,javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 cinoptions=j1,J1,(1s " see help cino-j cino-J cino-(
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the syntax file has good indenting for java script, visually highlight the block and press =.  This works for java so I would expect it to do something half decent for java script.  The results probably also depend on the settings of tabstop, expandtab and maybe shiftwidth.

gq is useful too, it formats lines rather than indents them.

Comment: Thanks for that. The combo I usually use for indenting a whole file is gg=G. My problem was that when I did this, JS didn't indent correctly. My own answer above solved the problem.