# How do I make vim indent JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

Vim 7.0.237 is driving me nuts with `indentexpr=HtmlIndentGet(v:lnum)`. When I edit JavaScript in a `<script>` tag indented to match the surrounding html and press enter, it moves the previous line to column 0. When I autoindent the whole file the script moves back to the right.

Where is vim's non-annoying JavaScript-in-HTML/XHTML indent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1830)?

Comment: Unfulfilling. I get a couple of decently indented function calls followed by a left-aligned var. Some people will find it pleasant that the plugin doesn't indent for <html> <head> or <body>, so the interesting structure of the document is less likely to be too far to the right.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620247/how-do-i-fix-incorrect-inline-javascript-indentation-in-vim) is similar question with accepted answer with links to two vim plugins:

1. [html improved indentation : A better indentation for HTML and embedded javascript](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1830) [mentioned by Manni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201509/how-do-i-make-vim-indent-javascript-in-html/1201590#1201590).
2. [OOP javascript indentation : This indentation script for OOP javascript (especially for EXTJS)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1936) .

One of them solved my problems with JavaScript scripts indention problems.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript).

It is an up-to-date plugin that properly indents javascript, including more recent developments like the syntax used in closures such as with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I toggle between `:set ai` and `:set noai`, but might be too tedious for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have plugins for indenting HTML and JavaScript files. To indent JavaScript *inside* HTML, I temporarily change the file type, select and indent the lines, and then change the file type back.

```
:filetype javascript
(select lines)
=
:filetype html
```

It's a little tedious, but it always produces the results I expect.