# Vim keeps messing up my javascript syntax within an html file

Tags: javascript, html, vim

Indentation is all wrong. Any help?

I specifically use the following settings for javascript:

```
au FileType javascript set foldmethod=indent foldlevel=0 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
```

How can I tell vim to identify a particular region within an .html file as javascript (thus applying those settings to that region)?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered here: [How do I fix incorrect inline Javascript indentation in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620247/how-do-i-fix-incorrect-inline-javascript-indentation-in-vim)

It's highly suggested you use the [JavaScript Indent : Javascript indenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081) plugin