# vim formatting JS wrong

Tags: javascript, vim

I've been using vim for a year or so now (on Ubuntu 10.04) and normally it's awesome. A few days back I added another plugin and suddenly all of my js indentation was wrong. HTML fine, XML fine, but any JS file, when I enter gg=G, it formats closed functions like below. Yikes!

I removed .vimrc from my home dir, added a different one, removed the new plugins, restarted several times, etc. Then I removed .vimrc and .vim from user's home dir and reinstalled using Synaptic. No change! I just want my old wonderful vim back... what can I do? Why does it persist beyond deletion and reinstall?

```
// Comment comment
$('#likeonfb .clickicon').click(function(e) {
                window.open('http://www.url.com','width=400,height=600');
                });
```

Comment: I did two things recommended in the following thread, which seem to have resolved the issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620247/how-do-i-fix-incorrect-inline-javascript-indentation-in-vim
I recreated my own .vim dir in my /home/user, and I installed javaScript Indenter there.  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081
And I recreated /home/user/.vimrc with the settings listed by another user in the same thread.
Then I reloaded .vimrc by entering :so % with the file open in vim.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it "persists" because it's a default setting. Vim right out of the box is missing most of what you want. Anyway, it should work fine if you add this to your .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Of course, this assumes your filetype is set correctly. `:set filetype?` does return `filetype=javascript`, right?

If your original indent files were somehow corrupted, of course, you can always install the [Javascript/HTML indentation plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had installed that plugin, and reinstalled it yesterday when I reinstalled everything else. Seems to have fixed almost everything. Seems to be the addition of closetag.vim that set everything off kilter...